# Creating chatbot using python

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api, uisearchbardelegate

I am currently working on creating a chatbot utilizing the Bard API, and I've encountered a challenge with the API key refresh rate. The Bard API cookies API key refreshes every 10-20 minutes, causing interruptions in the chatbot's functionality.

In an attempt to address this issue, I explored OpenAI, but as it is not a free option, it may not suit my requirements. My primary goal is to find a solution that allows the Bard API key to last longer or, alternatively, discover other free options with a more extended refresh rate.

What I tried:
I have implemented the Bard API in my chatbot, but the frequent refreshes of the API key have been disruptive to the chatbot's continuous operation. I am seeking advice on potential strategies or alternatives to extend the duration of the API key or explore other free options that offer a more extended refresh rate.

Expectations:
I'm looking for guidance and suggestions on how to overcome the Bard API key refresh rate issue, either by configuring settings or exploring alternative free options that provide a more extended duration between key refreshes. Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ooh appreciate for kind response

Answer (score 0):

I had embarked upon creating a chatbot with Python a long time ago too. I faced the exact same issues as you are right now.
I ended up using [FlowGPT](https://flowgpt.com/chat) and selenium(web scraping library in Python) to query and then scrape(using xpath), the response of chatGPT instance in FlowGPT website(It has other models too). You can also use selenium + [PI.AI](https://pi.ai/talk) for creating a chatbot. Here's a good youtube playlist for learning Selenium: [Selenium Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DD-ynCIZ4w&list=PLUDwpEzHYYLsuUBvuoYTlN0KsBB5t-BDa).